# How to pass the selected data from view to controller and again back to view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display the selected value in view. I am selecting a year in my view and passing that value to controller to filter my records. And again I need to pass that value to my view to display which value or year I selected. I don't have problem with filtering my record. My problem is I need to display which Year I selected. How do I do that?

When I run my application I am getting

System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyRecords.Models.ModelYear', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyRecords.Models.RecordsList]'.

Herer is my code.

### Index View

```
@model List<MyRecord.Models.RecordList>



var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
for (var i = year; i > 2012; i--)
{
    var j = @i - 1;
    <div class="col-md-1 ">
        @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "MyPage", new { i = i })
    </div>
}
```

**// Here I am Displaying which year I selected like 2010 and records of 2010**

```
<h3>@ModelYear.Year</h3> 
@foreach (var groupMonth in Model.GroupBy(recordLists => new { recordLists.date.Value.Year, recordLists.date.Value.Month }))
{
    <h3 class="monthHeader"> @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(groupMonth.Key.Month)</h3>
    foreach (var recordLists in groupMonth)
    {
        <div class="row">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialView", recordList)
        </div>
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Archives(int i = 0)
{
    var recordLists = new List<RecordList>();

    if(i == 0)
        recordLists = _db.recordlists
            .Where(p => p.date.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.date)
            .ToList();
    else
        recordLists = _db.recordlists
            .Where(p => p.date.Value.Year == i)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.date)
            .ToList();

     return View(new ModelYear{Records = recordLists, Year = i});
}
```

Model:

namespace MyRecord.Models

{

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

public partial class RecordList
    {

```
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
}

public class ModelYear
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public List<RecordList> Records { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: You tried to return ModelYear, but your view waiting for RecordList, you got the error in compile time?

Comment: Yes I got error in compile time

Comment: change in view model @model List<MyRecord.Models.RecordList> on ModelYear , I think its will help

Comment: Did it work? for the test, you can just comment another code in the view.

Comment: Yeah It worked.

Comment: But how do I get the values from both model class? how do combine both classes. Modelyear and RecordList class

Comment: check my answer please, is it clear? is it help? if i understand you just put Model.List or Model.Year this is the usual dto for data transfer between layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on comments

1) change in view model @model List on @model List

2) new model contains data year and recordlist, you can put inside what all you want.

you only need to remember that the model is hierarchical and not flat

```
foreach (var groupMonth in Model.RecordList.GroupBy(recordLists => new { recordLists.date.Value.Year, recordLists.date.Value.Month }))
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your explanation was very helpful.

Comment: your welcome) all the best!